# creating a multidimensional array from arrays in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an array of bar objects in php which consist of seven different attributes. The code I am using for this array is as follows:

```
$barsArray = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($barNameArray); $i++)
    {
        $barsArray[] = array('BarName' => $barNameArray[$i], 'first' => $firstCover[$i], 'timeFirst' => $firstTimes[$i], 
                                                                'second' => $secondCover[$i], 'timeSecond' => $secondTimes[$i], 
                                                                'third' => $thirdCover[$i], 'timeThird' => $thirdTimes[$i]);
    }
```

I have checked to make sure that all the other arrays are as I intend them. I just need to get this into one array of objects. Is this method completely off? Also, If I wanted to test to make sure that the correct objects are in the correct locations in a multidimensional array, how would I go about do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine (although you may want to cache the `count` instead of performing it repeatedly).

I can't say for sure, not knowing your greater purpose, but you may want to make `$barsArray` an associative array by the bar name. To do that, use `$barsArray[$barNameArray[$i]] =`, instead of `$barsArray[] =` (and of course remove the `BarName` property). This would not keep it in the original ordering, but would make getting a particular bar easier.

You can get an element from `$barsArray` like so: `$barsArray[3]['first']` (or `$barsArray['some_bar_name']['first']` if you change it to an associative array).

Comment: Using the loop shown, I tried to print out the contents of the first elements bar name with this statements:

echo  "<b> the first bar is $barsArray[0]['first'] </b> ";

however, the output resulted in:
the first bar is Array['first'] .... I checked the contents of the barNameArray at 0 and it was correct though

Comment: @Ranlou Try `echo "<b> the first bar is {$barsArray[0]['first']} </b> ";`